# Filter a list of key-value pair in a selected node in Ne04j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and have the following node structure in my graph

Name of the node : **Test**

```
{
  "A": "1",
  "B": "2",
  "C": "3",
  "D": "4",
  "E": "5",
  "F": "6"
}
```

My application requires the graph DB to return A, B and C as key-value pairs as-is from the node, something like

```
A | 1
B | 2
C | 3
```

I know how to return all the key-value pairs in a specific node using

```
MATCH (n:Test)
UNWIND keys(n) AS Parameter
RETURN Parameter,n[Parameter] as Value
```

I am stuck in getting only specific key-value pairs. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple tweak to your query to specify the keys you want.

For example, to just get the results for the keys 'A', 'B', and 'F':

```
MATCH (n:Test)
UNWIND ['A', 'B', 'F'] AS p
RETURN p, n[p] as Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this get you headed int he right direction?

Filter on a list of attributes that you want returned from the node?

```
MATCH (n:Test)
UNWIND keys(n) AS key
WITH n, key
ORDER BY key
WHERE key in ['A', 'B', 'C']
RETURN [key,n[key]]
```